# LoggerFactory Exception in Spring boot version 3.1.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-logback

I am getting following exception on bootRun task:

```
Exception in thread "main" java. lang.IllegalArgumentException:
LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on classpath.
Either remove logback or the competing implementation
( class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory loaded from 
file:home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-x/files-x.1/{org}/repo/snapshot/{random_number}/repo.jar.

**Using**
logback-classic version 1.4.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. Logback and SLF4J's NOPLoggerFactory are both present on the classpath and this is causing a conflict between these two logging implementations. NOPLoggerFactory might have been added as a transitive dependency by some other library you are using. To exclude it, write this in your build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-nop'
    }
}
```

Also, clear the gradle cache:

```bash
gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies
```